# Add resources (sound files) to exe? [MS Visual Studio 2012]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, resources, integrate

I currently have a "data" folder from which I load the .wav sound files that I use in my application. I load them like this

```
sf::Soundbuffer ss;
ss.loadFromFile("./data/sfx/sound.wav")
```

Is is possible to somehow integrate all those sound files into my .exe so I don't have to distribute them additionally? Kind of like statically linking libraries instead of dynamically so there's no need to provide them as separate dlls (I do that already). Is it possible and if yes, how would I load them then?

I already thought about converting the sound files and then hardcoding them in a char array and load them from memory, but if adding them to the exe works I don't have to do that and it would be much more convenient! Thanks ~

Comment: Read about "resources". You already used the term.

Answer (score 0):

Add the files to your project as resources, then you can use functions such as [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to use them. The sound files would be built into your exe image.

Comment: How exactly do I add a `.wav` file as a resource?